# What is the simplest way to allocate memory with hugepages by using C/C++ on Win/Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, winapi, posix

What is the simplest way to allocate memory in user-space with hugepages (with page size 2 MB or 1 GB) by using WINAPI/POSIX in C/C++ on Win/Linux?

CPU: x84_64

- WINAPI: Windows x64 7/10/Server 2012
- POSIX: Linux x64 (modern kernel)

Huge/Large page sizes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages

Comment: @David Heffernan On x86_64 page size may be: 4 KB, 2 MB or 1 GB. I am not about array size. This is a special term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages

Comment: I was going to give you a Windows answer, but I see you've accepted a Linux answer. In any case, you simply need to read the documentation.

Comment: For Windows, this is documented: [Large-Page Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720.aspx). To my knowledge, this is not exposed through POSIX or CRT extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Linux, you might pass `MAP_HUGETLB` (maybe also `MAP_HUGE_2MB` etc...) to [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (or perhaps [mmap2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap2.2.html)...)

See also your kernel's [Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt)

Gory details can be hardware-, kernel-, and computer- specific. See `/proc/meminfo` and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

(so if `mmap` with `MAP_HUGETLB` fails, try without it...).

BTW, you might have some implementation of `malloc`, or of [posix_memalign(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html), which might try to `mmap` with `MAP_HUGETLB` when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to have any special privilege to do this?

Comment: RTFM and the associated `Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt` in your kernel's source code; AFAIK, you need some special configuration somewhere, but I don't know the details (which could be hardware & kernel specific)

Answer (score 0):

WINAPI:
[VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
// alocate 1 MB
void* data = VirtualAlloc( NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
```

What's wrong with malloc or new?

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps we need this parameter MEM_LARGE_PAGES? I.e.: `void* data = VirtualAlloc( NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_LARGE_PAGES | MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366720(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Alex you can use MEM_LARGE_PAGES or not. It depends on your purposes. It's not required.

Comment: Do you mean that `VirtualAlloc()` always allocates Huge/Large pages with 2 MB page size by default? Can you tell me, since what Windows version is this happening?

Comment: @Alex Yes, VirtualAlloc can allocate huge/large portions of memory since this api function was introduced (Windows XP and Windows Server 2003).

Comment: @Alex if you allocate really large pages use MEM_LARGE_PAGES for optimization.

Comment: @Anton Alex asked about large pages specifically. -1. What I don't understand is why Alex asked the question if he already has the MSDN doc link, as evidenced by the first comment to this answer.

Comment: @David Heffernan Ok, I ask, because may be there is more simple or crossplatform way to do this, what I don't know. Also in Wiki-link from my question written about Huge pages (2 MB), and Large pages (1 GB) for x86_64. But in MSDN written about **MEM_LARGE_PAGES**. And I want exactly **Huge pages (2 MB)**. But now I see, that in MSDN MEM_LARGE_PAGES mean "typically 2 MB or greater" - i.e. this is Huge pages (2 MB): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366568(v=vs.85).aspx